# how to set width of the report dynamically in ireport based on number of columns

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Can i set the jrxml report width according to the data it contains.  That means is there any option to shrink or expand the report size according to the data.

i have created maximum of 15 columns for report and hiding/showing needed columns based on the input. reports columns getting hide but the page width remains the same,.

Anyone shed some light,. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the solution,.. 
  We can set the jrxml page width to maximum (say 1500) for 15 columns while design.
  And we can show/print the needed colums alone (say 10) based on user reports.
  We can set the page width at the run time using **jasperprint.setPageWidth()**

I have achieved this way,...

```
InputStream stream = ReportServlet.class.getResourceAsStream(file_location);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource ds = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data);
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(stream);
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hashMap,ds);
int noOfColumns = 10;           
jasperPrint.setPageWidth(noOfColumns * 100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didnt know this method exists jasperPrint.setPageWidth!!

Answer (score 0):

I never set up this feature, but i would have try to to look at the Print When Expression property.

A good start is to look at the documentation iReport Ultimate Guide : http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation, page 60.